# Play Protect show warning on my custom library

Tags: android, google-play-protect

I wrote an library for my applications to prevent doing some repetitive works and I implemented it as below in gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
 dependencies {
        implementation(name: 'd3', ext: 'aar')
    }
}
```

everything is good and all my applications with this library working without problem, but recently play protect show a warning that ask me send app for scanning. package that google wants to send is my library package not my app package and this is the problem because as I understood the way that warning disappear is publishing app on google play and I don't like to do this.
can someone tell me how to achieve  this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the min SDK version of your library. If that is set to default then some unnecessary permissions might be included.